# Different transcriptions for words with related origin

Tags: synonyms, loanwords

Sometimes, a single foreign word or etymologically related words from different dialects/related languages is/are incorporated into Japanese with different transcriptions/pronouncations and often different meanings. The most obvious and systematic ones are the different on-yomi's assigned to a single kanji, which came from different ancient dialects of Chinese.

> 明　(みん, めい, みょう)

Besides kanji, there are some with gairaigo:

> ガラス < glas (Dutch) 'glass, glass window'
> グラス < glass (English) 'glass cup'
>
> コップ < kop (Dutch) 'cup'
> カップ < cup (English) 'trophy cup'

Are there any other examples of gairaigo groups like this?

I would like to exclude those that are due to 平板化 (deaccentation) such as the following:

> クラブ (KUrabu) < club (English) 'club activities before/after school'
> クラブ (kuRABU) < id. 'host(ess) club'
>
> ゲーム (GEemu) < game (English) 'game'
> ゲーム (geEMU) < id. 'video game'

Comment: Just personal speculation: Pizza → ピザ (via English maybe?), ピッツァ (via Italian)

Comment: kuRABU.  Now that I think of it, it makes sense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few:

- truck → トロッコ (on rails), トラック (lorry)
- English → イギリス (via Portuguese "Inglez"), イングリッシュ
- letter → レッテル ("label", via Dutch), レター (letter, e.g. love letter)
- gear → ギヤ (gear, mechanical), ギア (gear = equipment [and less often, mechanical gear])
- chocolat(e) → ショコラ (via French), チョコレート (via English)
- curry → カレー, カリー

Comment: +1 for making me realise that イギリス comes from Inglez. I never realised

Answer (score 11):

I was recently told about a word with three different transcriptions with three different usages, which I cannot help sharing!

> [かるた](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9F&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na) (usually a specific kind of playing cards) < carta (Portuguese)
>   [カルテ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%86&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na) (a medical record) < Karte (German)
>   [カード](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na) (a card; a rectangular sheet, usually of paper) < card (English)

Answer (score 6):

Yay! Fun question (and I'm like half a year late)! I thought of a couple

> ゴム rubber, from Dutch gom
> ガム chewing gum, from English gum
>
> ストライク strike as in baseball
> ストライキ strike as in workers refusing to work
>
> アイアン iron as in golf
> アイロン iron as in ironing shirts

Answer (score 4):

ビール Beer (English?)
ビアガーデン Beer garden (English *via* German)

Comment: ビール is from Dutch _bier_. Listen to [the pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bier#Dutch).

Answer (score 3):

Buffet, which is usually バイキング (baikingu = viking), is sometimes represented as ビュッフェ (usually in on-train buffets) or as バフェ (in Okinawa only, which has a large US military presence), according to [Katakana Mysteries: 6 loan words Japan got wrong](http://nihonshock.com/2009/09/katakana-mysteries-6-loan-words-japan-got-wrong/).

Wiktionary gives キャラメル and カラメル for [caramel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caramel).

Answer (score 3):

dainichi's answer アイアン and アイロン reminded me of this:

> マシン 'machine' as in マシン語 'machine language' < machine (English)
> ミシン 'sewing machine' < machine (English)
>
> メリケン 'American' as in メリケン粉　'flour' < American (English)
> アメリカン 'American' < American (English)